# DataTable importRow() into empty table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I've been trying to merge an excel document with many sheets into a Datatable so that I can display said sheet in my winform app.

From reading around, I figured that Datatable.import(DataRow row) is my best bet. Thus my code looks as follows:

```
DataTable returnSet = new DataTable();
foreach (DataTable datTab in ds.Tables) // ds is extracted excel sheets in a dataset
{
  foreach (DataRow datRow in datTab.Rows) 
  {
    if (datRow.IsNull(0)) //if empty first col go on to next sheet
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      returnSet.ImportRow(datRow);
    }
  }
}
```

When debugging, it shows that datRow/datTab is what I expected it to be, however after each ImportRow, returnSet is still an empty 1x1 cell. Any insight as to what I am doing wrong / missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume the reason is because your DataTable currently has no schema. You can try to clone the original DataTable to create the same schema(DataColumns etc).

```
foreach (DataTable datTab in ds.Tables) // ds is extracted excel sheets in a dataset
{
    DataTable tblClone = datTab.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow datRow in datTab.Rows) 
    {

        if (datRow.IsNull(0)) //if empty first col go on to next sheet
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tblClone.ImportRow(datRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He'd want to declare the tblClone DataTable outside the DataTable loop, perhaps using the first DataTable in the DataSet as the template.

Comment: @JayRiggs: What means _template_? Does he want to skip all DataColumns that doesn't fit into the first table?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to return tblClone, but that is an easy fix. Thanks for the help. Just a brief thing, is there any way to simple attach on a row? When I test out iterating through multiple datatables and multiple datarows of above tables, it seems that the current row has to match the original schema EXACTLY, else it does not add the current row in. (I tested with 3 excel sheets, each with one row but, one with 3 columns of data, another with 4 columns, and another with 5 columns, only the 3 column row appeared, even though they appear parsed correctly in ds.)

Comment: My comment was poorly worded, sorry.  I believe the OP wants to combine all the DataTables in a DataSet into one new DataTable so I think in your code you'd have to declare this new DataTable outside your DataTable loop.  If you did that, you'd need to pick a DataTable to Clone in which case I'd suggest the DataTable at ds.Tables[0].  I could be wrong though.